# SQL SSRS and Report Builder

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Whether Report Builder 2.0 or 3.0 Comes along with SQL 2008 R2 Installation or we need to install it seperately ?

Whether Report Builder is different from SSRS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [SQL Server Report Builder 3.0 FAQ (DOCX file)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/F/D/7FDAA75C-1273-4DFE-8EC6-D9699C3EE47F/SQL_Server_2008_R2_Report_Builder_3_0FAQs.docx):

> *Where do I get access to Report Builder 3.0?*
>
> A. Report Builder 3.0 released as a **standalone download** as part of the
>   SQL Server 2008 Feature Pack and can be accessed through Microsoft
>   Download Center [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9f783224-9871-4eea-b1d5-f3140a253db6)

Report Builder **3.0** is the one that comes with SQL Server 2008 R2, 2.0 was the one with SQL Server 2008, and RB 1.0 shipped with SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services.

Answer (score 1):

Report Builder is a part of SQL Server Reporting Services. It is a "ClickOnce" application that will install on a client PC from the SSRS website provided with Reporting Services. Report Builder requires a Report Model project in Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS), which is also a part of SQL Server - providing you choose to install it.

With SQL Server 2008 R2, there is a Reporting Services site setting that you can choose whether Report Builder 1, 2, or 3 is the default application when a user clicks the button for Report Builder. However, with the correct URL, you can have users run any version if they choose. Just keep in mind that reports built with a higher version of Report Builder cannot be opened in older versions.